# Understanding type coercion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, type-coercion

I know `==` operator performs the type coercion. But I can't understand the below behaviour.

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);

if (x) {
  console.log("if(x) is true");
}

if (x == false) {
  console.log("if(x == false) is true");
}
```

Surprisingly, above snippet prints both lines:

`if(x) is true
if(x == false) is true`

Can someone explain this weird behaviour or there is something fundamental I'm missing?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Then why statement evaluates to true

Comment: This isn't a type coercion thing, this is a boxing thing. This is exactly why you don't do `new Boolean()` or `new Number()` or `new String()`.

Comment: Please refer to the following documentation from the well-versed [Kyle Simpson](https://github.com/getify) about [Falsy Objects](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md#falsy-objects). I actually suggest you read the whole book that is there for free.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by other answers, that's because `x` is an Object – a Boolean object, but still an object, since you're using the `new` operator – and is coerced only when you compare `x` to `false`: the `if (x)` is checking if `x` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, and therefore doesn't need coercion (there are no other operands involved): an object is always "true" (weeeell… almost always: `typeof null` returns `object` but it's a falsy value. But that's another story…).

You can easily checking when the coercion is invoked tapping the [toPrimitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) symbol:

```
var x = new Boolean(false);

// first of all, if it wasn't an object you couldn't
// do this
x[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function(hint) {
  console.log({hint});
  return this.valueOf();
}

// no console.log yet
if (x) {
  console.log("if(x) is true");
}

// here you got the console.log before the one
// inside the block, since the coercion happens
// in the `if`
if (x == false) {
  console.log("if(x == false) is true");
}
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand it. If x is truthy value coercion should convert it to true and thence, x == false should be false in second if statement, but that's not the case

Comment: I think you're missing the foundation of coercion: it happens when you compare *two* things: you need *two* *operands*. `if (x)` doesn't compare `x` with anything: it just check that `x` is a truthy value – attention! "truthy" not "equals to `true`", and "truthy" is not a *type* per se, hence no coercion. When you do `x == false`, you're comparing *two* things, and since you're using the abstract equality (`==`) the coercion is performed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Boolean(false)` instead of `new Boolean(false)`, since `Boolean` is a function.

Otherwise you get an empty object `{}`, which is not the same type as what is returned by the function itself, which is a `boolean`.

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);
const y = Boolean(false);

console.log(x, typeof x);
console.log(y, typeof y);
```

In the your first test, you only check if the value is truthy, and an empty object is truthy, since `x = {}`, the test passes:

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);

console.log(x, !!x, !!{}, Boolean(x))

if (x) {
  console.log("if(x) is true");
}
```

However, when using `==`, the operator coerces `new Boolean(false)` to its primitive value using [`x.valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) which is `false` and thus the equality passes.

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);

console.log(x.valueOf())
```

Answer (score 1):

`new Boolean(false)` produces an object. Objects are always [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) even if they wrap a falsy primitive value. For example, `new String("")` is also truthy despite `""` being falsy.

On the other hand, when you do `new Boolean(false) == false`, it coerces the object to its primitive value for the comparison. Incidentally, `new Boolean(false) === false` is *not* true, since their types don't match.

As a general rule, you shouldn't use object constructors for primitive types unless you have a specific reason for it, to avoid unexpected behavior like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);
```

`typeof x` will return `object`. The type `object` is "[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)", which means it evaluates to true if there's no operator like `==`. However, the value of it is `false`, which is why the second statement evaluates to true as well.

So the `if` statements behave differently, because the `if` without operator checks whether the type is truthy or falsy (in this case truthy -> true) and the if with the comparison (==) calls `.valueOf()` which is `false`.

You shouldn't be using `new` wrappers for this scenario anyway.

```
const x = false;
```

is enough. For casting, you can use `Boolean()` without `new` wrapper.

To check whether a value is truthy, you can use a double negation:

```js
const x = new Boolean(false);

if (x) console.log(!!x);

if (x == false) console.log(x.valueOf());
```

Answer (score 1):

when you do `if (expression)` in javascript the expression is evaluated by being cast to a boolean.

Somewhat confusingly, `Boolean(new Boolean(false))` evaluates to true because as Nick said it is still an object. This is what is causing the behaviour you're confused about.

Good read for more info https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/